# huge difference between the running time of the same SQL query in java and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a function as follow:

```
public static ArrayList<Article> getNewsList(Database db, Date start,Date end,int nextNth,int limit,String tableName,String entityQuery,String topicQuery) throws SQLException {
    long a=System.currentTimeMillis();
    ArrayList<Article> youTube=new ArrayList<Article>();
    System.out.println("starting time is : "+a+"    ");
    Connection conn = db.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn
            .prepareStatement("SELECT n.title,n.link,n.Description,n.NewsContent,n.IURL,date(n.Published) FROM "+tableName+" as en inner join news as n on "
                    + " en.dataitemid=n.id where en.dataitemtype=1 and dateAdded between ? and ? "+entityQuery+"  "+topicQuery+" limit ?,?;");
    stmt.setDate(1, start);
    stmt.setDate(2, end);
    stmt.setLong(3, nextNth);
    stmt.setLong(4, limit);

    ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rset.next()) {
            Article nw=new Article();
            nw.setTitle(rset.getString(1));
            nw.setLink(rset.getString(2));
            nw.setDescription(rset.getString(3));
            nw.setContent(rset.getString(4));
            nw.setiURL(rset.getString(5));
            nw.setDate(rset.getDate(6));

            youTube.add(nw);
        }
        long b=System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(b+" total time it takes is: "+(b-a));
    return youTube;
}
```

this function acts very funny. As you see I have 2 variables for starting and ending time of the function and when I run the function it takes 36 seconds(the result of b-a)

but if I run the same query with the same parameters in mysql it takes only 0.019 seconds which shows the huge difference though as you can see I do not have anything special in my java code that takes long time . I am so curious to know what causes this huge difference. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hook up a profiler to your code to find out the hot spots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be network latency / errors involved here. Try moving you a and b timing just before and just after the execute and have a look at that value. In your example you don't mention how many rows you are retrieving but this might be effecting your timings.

Comment: I am retrieving 100 rows

Comment: And what is your timing if you move the a and b to before and after the executeQuery() ?

Comment: between 26 to 29 but in database it takes 0.019

Comment: Please do a show create for each table in the query as well as a explain extended output for your query and add it to your question. What version of MySQL are you running

Comment: My gut says that this could be a connection problem are you running the program on the same box ?

Answer (score 0):

Before making query call, it has to do number of things, Load JDBC driver(In class of the object `db`), Establish connection and then it fires the query.

Thus overall time required is very much. If you put `long a=System.currentTimeMillis();` just before `stmt.executeQuery()` and `long b=System.currentTimeMillis();` just after it, you will see some improvement.

Comment: 36 seconds vs. 0.019 seconds? I doubt that has to do with the JDBC driver.

Comment: @VivinPaliath thanks for your answer I tried to do what you said but now it takes 29 sec which is still huge

Comment: @VallabhPatade What? How can the mere act of observing the time difference create an improvement?! There is no observer effect here.